# How to setup domain email for a site that uses Github Pages?

Tags: domains, dns, email, github

I've purchased a domain, built the site documentation in Jekyll but now I need email accounts for that domain I have forwarding to the Github Pages repo. Per research I did not see this question asked. In the DNS of the company I am using do I just need to add the hosting account I have, such as Hostgator with the nameserver accounts for Github? In the end I would have four listed nameservers if I am understanding the setup correctly.

How should a domain setup be completed if the site is hosted with Github Pages but I need domain name email accounts, such as foobar@website.com?

Answer (score 1):

Email hosting DNS setup is generally completely independent of web hosting DNS setup. So GitHub Pages won't get in the way of setting up email at all.

> that domain I have forwarding to the Github Pages repo

Are you *hosting* content on your domain using GitHub Pages, or does your domain *redirect* (forward) the user to github.com? I'm almost certain that you mean the former, but the terminology is important.

> In the DNS of the company I am using do I just need to add the hosting account I have, such as Hostgator with the nameserver accounts for Github?

GitHub does not host nameservers for use by customers (GitHub Pages does not provide DNS service, only hosting service), so you will need to keep your nameservers with Hostgator.

> In the end I would have four listed nameservers if I am understanding the setup correctly.

In the end, you will have only Hostgator nameservers. Those nameservers will be serving four (or more) DNS records: `A` and/or `CNAME` records for web hosting (pointing both the naked and `www` versions of the domain to GitHub Pages), and `MX` and `TXT` records  for email hosting (directing incoming email and authenticating outgoing email).

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you're using a [custom domain](https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site) (you need to be able to configure the domain's DNS records).
2. Set up an email server; find a provider or host one yourself.
3. Add an MX record to your DNS host/registrar.